# BufferUnderflowException

Tags: android, bluetooth, bytebuffer

In a Bluetooth app , i'm receiving data from a external device in byte[].
then putting data into ByteBuffer for further use

like shown below

```
        ByteBuffer localByteBuffer = null;
        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[4096];

          int bytes = 0;
          Log.d("ZeoTest", "++++ Listening...");
          while (true) {

              try {
                    bytes = in.read(arrayOfByte);
                    localByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(arrayOfByte);

                    localByteBuffer.get(arrayOfByte, 0, arrayOfByte.length);

                    Log.d("Zeo", "input :"+((localByteBuffer))); 
                    String data =bytesToHex(arrayOfByte) ;
                    Log.d("Zeo", "input stream :"+(new String(data))); 
                    Log.d("ZeoTest", "++++ Read "+ bytes +" bytes");

              } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                  try { Thread.sleep(0); } catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
              } Log.d("ZeoTest", "++++ Done: test()");

              onReceive(localByteBuffer);}   }
```

In onReceive methode checking header is valid or no...

as shown below

```
  public static boolean isValidHeader(EnhancedByteBuffer paramEnhancedByteBuffer)
  {
    boolean bool = false;
    if (paramEnhancedByteBuffer.remaining() < 12);
    while (true)
    {

      paramEnhancedByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
      int i = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.position();
      long l = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint32();
      paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint16();
      int j = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint8();
      int k = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint8();
      paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getBoolean();
      paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint8();
      int m = paramEnhancedByteBuffer.getUint16();
      paramEnhancedByteBuffer.position(i);
      if ((l == 1196641608L) && (j <= 2) && (k < 14) && (m == MessageType.getMessageContentSize(k)))
        bool = true;
           return bool;
    }
  }
```

but getting buffer under flow exception on getUint32 method

**what may be possible reason...????**

**logcat....**

```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.getInt(HeapByteBuffer.java:117)
at com.myzeo.zeo.utility.EnhancedByteBuffer.getUint32(EnhancedByteBuffer.java:87)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest.isValidHeader(ZeoTest.java:195)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest.isValidHeader(ZeoTest.java:183)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest.onReceive(ZeoTest.java:153)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest.setup(ZeoTest.java:125)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest.access$0(ZeoTest.java:64)
at com.myzeo.bluetooth.ZeoTest$1.onClick(ZeoTest.java:47)   
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2629)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9374)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: the reason was when i get data to bytebuffer (ex: 5ytes).. position will be 5... so before passing bytebuffer to access data byte by byte set position to 0.... ie.. `localByteBuffer.position(0);`

Answer (score 3):

The possible reason is that you read more bytes from the buffer than are available. Check the buffer's position after each read() in debugger to see which call advances the buffer more than it should (maybe readBoolean())

Answer (score 2):

You didn't consider the **position** of the reading head.

If you want to get an integer value, and the reading head is at position 4 of a ByteBuffer that has a capacity of 4, then you will get a BufferUnderflowException, because he can not read 4 more bytes for the integer value to be returned.

You have to give him the reading position (non-persistent): **getInt( position );** e.g.: getInt( 0 );